# Text output to console in VUE

Tags: vue.js

Please help me with code for vue

Me need get text in console.log with design how in screen.

[image: a busy cat]

How i can get it?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want a background color for your console.log.

Here is an example (open console to see it) :

```js
console.log('%cThis is a text with a background color', 'background: #27e887; color: #ffffff');
```